# new sequence column and want to make it is a primary key

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence

I wanted to make a add a new sequence column and want to make it is a primary key.I am trying with

```
create sequence rid_seq;
alter table test add column rid integer default nextval('rid_seq');
```

But this sometimes doesn't give unique sequence?ANy other way?Any help is appreciated

Comment: `alter table test add column rid bigserial primary key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sequence does not have  attribute unique or not, so you have to add unique index on the column, that uses sequence values. In your case (you want to add a primary key) just use "shortcuts":

```
alter table test add column rid bigserial primary key
```